# Make view depend on variables in laravel

Tags: php, templates, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

It might just be me coming from a more restricted java background, but I'm feeling the connection between views and controllers in Laravel is error prone. For example, consider a controller looking something like this

```
ReceiptController extends BaseController {
    ...
    public function show() {
        $data = array($receipt, $offer);
        View::make('registration', $data);
    }
}
```

and a view which depends on a receipt object and an offer string

```
...
<div id="receipt">
    <h1>Receipt</h1>
    {{$receipt->items}}
    @if ($receipt->price > 10000)
        <p>{{$offer}}</p>
    @endif;
</div>
...
```

What if a controller somewhere don't include the offer string? Worst case scenario it might go unnoticed until someone purchase something with a price over 10000. How would I go about throwing an error if the controller doesn't pass all variables required to make the view? Bonus if it also makes an IDE such as PHPStorm recognize the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [view composer](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers), and ensure that whenever your receipt view is called, a offer is always included. That way you know the object is always passed.

```
View::composer('receipt', function($view)
{
    $view->with('offer', Offer::get(1));
});
```

Or you could just handle it directly in your view

```
<div id="receipt">
    <h1>Receipt</h1>
    {{$receipt->items}}
    @if ($receipt->price > 10000)
       <p>{{$offer or 'Sorry - no special available'}}</p>
    @endif;
</div>
```

Lastly - the 'best' option is to always [test your code](http://laravel.com/docs/testing), and check your view is always called with a $offer variable

```
 $this->assertViewHas('offer');
```

Comment: It  leaves me a bit unsatisfied, but handling it in the view as you suggested is the best way of doing it I suppose. What do you think of doing it something like this?

if(!(isset($receipt) && isset($offer) && etc...) {
        throw new Exception("Not all data this view depends on has been set");
    }

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot throw an exception inside a view - its too late (I just tried it, and I couldnt get the exception to show).

Answer (score 0):

That kind of logic if intented to work in the Controller, if the price is higher than a value, set a $var = false and check if in the view.

```
if($receipt->price > 10000) {
   $offer = $offer;
} else {
   $offer = false;
}
```

And about the compatibility between PHPStorm and Blade Template Engine, PHPStorm 7.1 doesn't support it, but you help to build a better world voting for it for the next version: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-14172

Comment: My reasoning over having the check in the view is that it makes the app more modular and readable. I did vote for the issue, however it's not something I find critical.